# How to use if condition, if first valuable is above zero, then result needs to zero?

Tags: swift, if-statement, return-value

```
let apliekamasumma = Double(brutoalga! - socnoalgas - summaapg - 75)

if (apliekamasumma < 0) {
    let apliekamasumma = 0
}
```

Please help me with this code.

Comment: You already have declared `apliekamasumma` on the first line as a constant. If you want to be able to change its value, use a variable instead. And do not redeclare it later, just use it. Please read the [Swift manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) chapter one, "The basics", it's very well written.

Answer (score 2):

You can construcct a two-element array with the calculated value and 0, then use `minElement`:

```
let apliekamasumma = [Double(brutoalga! - socnoalgas - summaapg - 75), 0].minElement()!
```

Or as suggested by David Berry:

```
let apliekamasumma = min(Double(brutoalga! - socnoalgas - summaapg - 75), 0)
```

Comment: On a second reading, your question doesn't align with your code. Your title says "zero if above" but your code say "zero if below". Play around with `minElement()` and `maxElement()` to get what you want.

Comment: Better to just use `min(Double(brutoalga! - socnoalgas - summaapg - 75), 0)` or `max(...)` depending on which they're really trying to.  With only two elements, don't really need the complexity of `minElement`

Comment: @DavidBerry thank for the sugesstion, forgot about these simple functions

Answer (score 1):

```
func sum(brutoalga:Double, socnoalgas:Double, summaapg:Double) ->Double{

    var apliekamasumma = brutoalga - socnoalgas - summaapg - 75.0

    if (apliekamasumma < 0) {
        return 0.0
    }
    return apliekamasumma
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var apliekamasumma = Double(brutoalga! - socnoalgas - summaapg - 75)

if apliekamasumma < 0 {
   apliekamasumma = 0
}
```